# jenkins keeps throwing Bad Message 431 reason: Request Header Fields Too Large

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have recently upgraded to jenkins 2.89.4(jdk8). I am continuously getting below error on a redirected page whenever I go into the configuration tab of any jenkins job.

```
Bad Message 431

reason: Request Header Fields Too Large
```

There is not enough help available on jenkins pages.
The workaround I have is to go and remove the cookies but I see the same page again after 2-3 redirection.

Answer (score 75):

As per official [issue thread](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25046) in the jenkins site,`Cookies` are the main reason for this. More times you (re)start the server, it will create more session ID's. This is the main culprit for this reason. So please delete your cookies and try again. It will work again. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did see that. That does solve the problem as I have mentioned in my question. The page gets loaded but again it throws the same error again and again. without any jenkins restart.

Comment: Clearing the cookies seems to have worked for me. Before I cleared them I would refresh the page and get the scenario you are talking about where eventually it would give the same error again. Now after clearing the cookies for my particular domain/sub-domain, it is working.
Not sure what is different in your Jenkins env setup.

Answer (score 8):

the browser has many cookie data it try to send that big data to the jenkins server. we need to clear cookie data, so it will auto create necessery cookie data to send to jenkins server.

how to solve:
eg on Firefox

1. open jenkins web, eg http://127.0.0.1:8080
2. right click on browser
3. click Inspect
4. click tab Storage
5. click Cookies
6. right click and choose delete all
7. open jenkins web again, eg http://127.0.0.1:8080

Answer (score 4):

Opening Jenkins page on incognito mode temporarily solves the issue

Comment: I have multiple temporary solutions. Looking for a concrete one.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same behaviour trying to access jenkins through a reverse-proxy, 
when jenkins installation was not yet completed.
I finished the installation by directing a browser directly on the VM hosting jenkins,
and only later configured nginx following the officiel instruction [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy)